# Can I perform a dump tran mid-transaction? Also, effects of using delay on log?

Tags: sql, sybase

Good day,

Two questions:
A) If I have something like this:

```
COMPLEX QUERY
WAIT FOR LOG TO FREE UP (DELAY)
COMPLEX QUERY
```

Would this actually work? Or would the log segment of tempdb remain just as full, due to still holding on to the log of the first query.

B) In the situation above, is it possible to have the middle query perform a dump tran with truncate_only ?

(It's a very long chain of various queries that are run together. They don't change anything in the databases and I don't care to even keep the logs if I don't have to.)

The reason for the chain is because I need the same two temp tables, and a whole bunch of variables, for various queries in the chain (Some of them for all of the queries). To simply the usage of the query chain by a user with VERY limited SQL knowledge, I collect very simple information at the beginning of the long script, retrieve the rest automatically, and then use it through out the script

I doubt either of these would work, but I thought I may as well ask.

Sybase versions 15.7 and 12 (12.? I don't remember)

Thanks,
Ziv.

---

Per my understanding of @michael-gardner 's answers this is what I plan:

```
FIRST TEMP TABLES CREATION
MODIFYING OPERATIONS ON FIRST TABLES
COMMIT
QUERY1: CREATE TEMP TABLE OF THIS QUERY 
QUERY1: MODIFYING OPERATIONS ON TABLE
QUERY1: SELECT
COMMIT
(REPEAT)
DROP FIRST TABLES (end of script)
```

I read that 'select into' is not written to the log, so I'm creating the table with a create (I have to do it this way due to other reasons), and use select into existing table for initial population. (temp tables)
Once done with the table, I drop it, then 'commit'.
At various points in the chain I check the log segment of tempdb, if it's <70% (normally at >98%), I use a goto to reach the end of the script where I drop the last temp tables and the script ends. (So no need for a manual 'commit' here)

I misunderstood the whole "on commit preserve rows" thing, that's solely on IQ, and I'm on ASE.

Comment: * The reason for the chain is because I need the same two temp tables, and a whole bunch of variables, for various queries in the chain (Some of them for all of the queries). To simply the usage of the query chain by a user with VERY limited SQL knowledge, I collect very simple information at the beginning of the long script, retrieve the rest automatically, and then use it through out the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumping the log mid-transaction won't have any affect on the amount of log space.  The Sybase log marker will only move if there is a commit (or rollback), AND if there isn't an older open transaction (which can be found in `syslogshold`)

There are a couple of different ways you can approach solving the issue:

- Add log space to tempdb.

This would require no changes to your code, and is not very difficult.  It's even possible that tempdb is not properly sized for the sytem, and the extra log space would be useful to other applications utilizing tempdb.

- Rework your script to add a commit at the beginning, and query only for the later transactions.

This would accomplish a couple of things.  The commit at the beginning would move the log marker forward, which would allow the log dump to reclaim space.  Then since the rest of your queries are only reads, there shouldn't be any transaction space associate with them.  Remember the transaction log only stores information on Insert/Update/Delete, not Reads.

Int the example you listed above, the users details could be stored and committed to the database, then the rest of the queries would just be select statements using those details for the variables, then a final transaction would cleanup the table.  In this scenario the log is only held for the first transaction, and the last transaction..but the queries in the middle would not fill the log.

Without knowing more about the DB configuration or query details it's hard to get much more detailed.

Comment: First of all, thank you! @michael-gardner
Regarding your first solution, I am not allowed to make changed to any element of the db that I did not create myself.
Regarding your second solution, this might help.

So, to use this method I would have to (in pseudo code) do something like this: --
`CREATE AND POPULATE ALL TEMP TABLES AND VARIABLES --
COMMIT --
SELECT (of any level of complexity? What about the work tables Sybase creates for this work?) --
DUMP EVERYTHING AT THE END PHASE` --
So, the transaction log of tempdb would be cleared before the SELECTs and barely/not be used after?

Comment: I'm sorry for the format of the code example in my reply, I'm fairly newish to this site and still don't know how to use the systems here properly.

Comment: @ziv Assuming you aren't using SELECT INTO, I don't believe any of the selects should be logged (but can't verify this).  As for the tempdb log, whether the log clears depends on the settings.  If 'trunc log on chkpt' option is set  (shown in output of sp_dboptions), then yes it will clear on it's own, or if you issue a manual CHECKPOINT.  Otherwise you'll have to use DUMP TRAN to free up the space.  Assuming there are no older transactions, then it will free up the space to the point after the commit.

Comment: I do use select intos in certain queries. So, per your answers, I'm thinking I'll convert them all to "created" tables. Another thing to note about this, is that I do use updates, deletes and inserts, after the table creation, followed by the selects that use the table. In this method, I would finish all modifying operations on the table, and then I can just use the commit? Also, I'd need to add "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS", to the temp tables I create at the start of the chain, since they are used by everything in the chain, right?
Would this assure the log stays clean?

Comment: , Also, can I get the script to check if the log is filling up (this I can do), and if it is, have it perform a dump tran? Or would this be impossible from within the chain? (Assume addition of commits at various points of the chain)

Comment: @ziv depends on how you create the table.  If you use a #tablename, then there are some limitations in scope to a session/procedure.  If you specify tempdb..tablename, then it has a global scope, and should be available until the system is restarted.  As for script to check log space..I believe `sp_helpdb tempdb` will give you a log free kbyte output, so if you needed more than that you can look at the underlying code for sp_helpdb` and create a script to get the output you are looking for.  I believe the ON COMMIT command may be a Sybase IQ command, and not a Sybase ASE command.

Comment: And assuming there are commits along the way - dumping the tran mid-chain should free up log space.

Comment: I'm using #temp-tables, I have a query I prepared to fetch the log free percentage (in numeric(3,2) format), and there are commits after every heavy query. From what I could gleam from Sybase Info Center though, using temp tables and 'dump trans' inside the chain is not possible together. Have I misunderstood? 
The chain starts with the user setting 3 variables, and pressing F9, that F9 runs the entire chain in one go. I placed log-checked at various places, along with commits. A) Can I add 'dump tran' to that? B) Does commit, on it's own, free up log, or do I have to dump?